# Should we have two sets of country-specific tags — one for country of origin, one for country of location? With what nomenclature?

Tags: discussion, tags

I tagged a question [france](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/france) and [usa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa), but realised the tags alone still make it ambiguous whether it's a French in the USA or a US citizen in France.  Should we have *two* tags for each country: one relating to people with a passport from that country, and one relating to people living there?

If yes, what is a good nomenclature to do so?

Comment: What were you thinking, something like `to-country` and `from-country`?

Answer (score 9):

It's actually a bit more complicated than that, as we have (at least) three country-statuses which may come up:

- Country/ies of citizenship
- Country/ies of residency
- Country/ies of visitation

I think [x-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-citizens) makes the most sense for the first.

Whether we want to use tags to distinguish between the others is debatable. Travel.SE doesn't bother with a distinction, although their niche is slightly different.

[x-residents](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-residents) might be just as well, along with simply [x](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x), for questions about a specific country, including how to visit there based on your citizenship/residency status (although many such questions should be redirected to Travel.SE).

Comment: I think having a single tag that handles these 3 statuses is important, but citizens and residents doesn't do it for me.

Comment: @StrongBad: What do you propose?

Comment: I think I like XX-to/XX-from and maybe a XX-citizens for questions that depend on the citizenship (e.g., getting a visa).

Comment: @StrongBad: Which sorts of questions would these apply to?  Generally just logistical questions, right?  "How do I move my car from France to Nepal?" Are such questions really a very good fit for this site in the first place? If so, wouldn't simply the addition of a [tag:from-france] be sufficient along with the existing [tag:nepal]?

Comment: You should join us in chat ...

Comment: Why make "to" and "from" postpositions into rather prepositions than normal like English in?

Answer (score 3):

I've seen [`us-citizen`](//expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-citizen) pop up already, and this seems to handle the issue pretty well.

So I'd propose that any questions about moving to / living in a certain country should use that country's name as the tag. Any questions for which the original nationality matters could use `xyz-citizen` as an additional tag, though preferably **only** when actually relevant..

Comment: With the name of the country or the demonym?  [tag:netherlands-citizen], [tag:dutch-citizen], [tag:nl-citizen]?

Comment: I'm **just** adding a new question to encompass that and similar issues :)

Comment: This is fine, but I'd highly recommend sticking to plurals. We found this very inconsistent on travel, but by making them always plural eg [tag:us-citizens] we seem to have cleaned it up a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think in general we want to tag questions with the country about which expertise is required. So if you are living in the [UK and need to get a background check done in the US](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/845/us-version-of-the-uk-crb) or if you are living in [Mexico and need to register your car in the US](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/860/how-can-i-renew-my-us-vehicle-registration-while-out-of-the-country/890#890) the the correct tag is [usa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) since you need help from people who know the US system and they don't really need to know about the UK/Mexico systems. This type of usage does not reflect the [usa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) wiki

> Living in the United States of America as an expatriate.

Other questions have obvious citizenship requirements. For example a [US citizen moving to Paraguay](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/661/how-to-acquire-permanent-residency-in-paraguay) the citizenship matters and the country that they are moving to matters, but the fact that they are currently in the US doesn't really matter. In this case [us-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-citizens) and [paraguay](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paraguay) are useful but [usa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) would not be particularly helpful. This type of usage reflects the [us-citizens](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-citizens) wiki

> For questions pertaining to citizens of the United States of America.

Comment: A Dutch citizen licving in the US but needs to move to Netherlands should use the dutch-citizen and uk tags, as legal stuff (visas, work permits, etc.) depend on your nationality and not on your current residency. We also need to know wheter it's actually important that the user comes from the USA or not.