# Should we extend "Belgium" tag to include citizens?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/15420/registering-for-the-elections-2019) is about an issue affecting an ex-pat Belgian citizen.  It doesn't have a tag indicating the location, mainly because there isn't a suitable tag.  There *is* a tag "Belgium", but that is for "issues affecting ex-pats *in* Belgium" (my emphasis).

It only has 28 questions, which suggests that adding a few more won't overload it.  I suspect that many people who watch the "belgium" tag are likely to be able to offer advice to citizens too.

Adding a "belgian-citizen" tag feels like overkill, but it is the obvious alternative.

Comment: I think this is addressed in https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172/what-does-the-xx-citizens-tag-mean

Comment: @StrongBad Which is actually a duplicate of https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/should-we-have-two-sets-of-country-specific-tags-one-for-country-of-origin-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now let's use the current scheme where [belgium](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belgium) refers to any question about being resident in Belgium, and [belgian-citizen](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belgian-citizen) for any question where the question is about someone who has Belgian citizenship. While there's definitely an overlap, I don't really see an issue with adding separate tags to make it more in-line with our other tags, as there are enough differences between the meaning of the two tags.

Note that after adding the tag it might be worth going through the [belgium](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belgium) tag and checking whether any of them could be re-tagged or addiotionally tagged [belgian-citizen](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belgian-citizen)

Comment: Oo! I didn't know I could create tags!